# good practice to 'store' extra data in req.params

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am trying to create a RESTful API for an web app I create.

During the creation on different routes and then creating the logic for each route, I found it useful to store any additional data I wanted in the req object in params attribute. (`req.params`).

To be more precise, as I had a route of the form

```
/resource1/:resource1id/resource2/:resource2id/
```

When I get data from my database about that resource and I want to keep that info, i store it in the `req.params` to use it in another function to produce the response I want.

Is that a good practice?
Should I have done it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By studying the [express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) documentation I found that extra data can be saved into [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) and/or `app.locals` object.